# In which .net dll file the <input> element tag is used to show to the browser

Tags: .net, asp.net

I need to know the .net dll file name in which it uses the  to show to the browser a input element.

Actually in php elemets are used hard codedly. But in .net we are inherit the files to show an input text but i need to know the file name or dll name in which the html tag is written.

Did you get me.Because i am sure that .net dll files use these html element to show the pages in browser.

Comment: What would the `dll` name give you? ASP.NET does not work like PHP. Why do you need this information?

Comment: I think that you better tell what you are trying to accomplish, because usually there is no need to know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking at the `Microsoft.Web.UI.WebControls.dll` ? if this is what you are looking at, then it is normally found in the GAC folder.

[System.Web.UI.HtmlControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tct4wcsd%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Several ASP.net elements are rendered using `<input>`, obvious example is `asp:Button`. It is defined in System.Web.dll with all standard Web Controls. I really don't know how this could be helpful.